# How to show "count" query result in jTextField from MS SQL

Tags: java

I wanted to display count of books in the database using jTextField but it keeps showing this message "The index 1 is out of range". the following is the code I wrote:

```
private  void CountBooks(){
     try{
         String q = "USE BookstoreRecord; SELECT COUNT(Title) AS Tiltle FROM Books;";
         Connection conn = DBconnection.getCon();
         ResultSet rs;
          PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(q);
          ps.setInt(1, 20);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
         if(rs.next())
         jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1)));
     }catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Comment: may i know 20 is what bookId ?

Comment: Please show us the table description

Comment: where is index of the parameter(?) to insert the value

Comment: see I have 3 books recorded in the database, I just want to display 3 in the jTextField. and ps.setInt(1, 20); this I found in here.

Comment: the error message tells you that there is no "`?` number 1" (i.e. parameter) in your query, so remove `ps.setInt(1, 20);` it makes no sense. You might also want to clean resources (`conn`, etc). See also the [javadoc of `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this,

I guess from someMethod()...

```
jTextField2.setText(CountBooks()));
```

into CountBooks()...

```
 //ps.setInt(1, 20); **/* remove it, it does not required for it... */**

if(rs.next())
{
   return Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Tiltle"));
}
```

Comment: why do I have to return a value and set the text can't I just set it in the if statement?

Comment: exactly right. you can do it. but generally method name like countBooks(), so idea is make that method's code into more specific like count only rather than set elsewhere(here, into textfield).

Comment: I changed it like this now it shows an other message "The ResultSet has no current raw" but it should have.

Comment: kindly, Accept my answer.